# FFT in python gives different results

Tags: python, fft

I am working on a project with an RaspberryPi, where I have connected an USB microphone and I have recorded a *.wave* file.
Once I have that, I wanted to implement Fourier Transformation, Low pass filter and inverse transform it.
My codes are mostly based on examples from StackOverflow, so I will post them here as well:

```
#Code 1
fs, data = wavfile.read('test1.wav') # load the data
b=[(element/2**8.)*2-1 for element in data] # this is 16-bit track, b is now normalized on [-1,1)
c = fft(b) # calculate fourier transform (complex numbers list)
d = len(c)/2  # you only need half of the fft list (real signal symmetry)
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(data)
plt.plot(abs(c[:(d-1)]),'r') 

plt.show()

#Code 2
sampling_length = 5.0 # measured 3sec
fs, data = wavfile.read("test1.wav")
Fs = 1.0/sampling_length
ls = range(len(data)) # data contains the function
freq = np.fft.fftfreq(len(data), d = sampling_length)
fft = np.fft.fft(data)
x = freq[:len(data)/2] 
for i in range(len(x)):
        if x[i] > 0.005: # cut off all frequencies higher than 0.005
                fft[i] = 0.0
                fft[len(data)/2 + i] = 0.0
inverse = np.fft.ifft(fft)
```

The first code is supposed just to give the Fourier transformation, while the second it should further do a Low Pass filter and inverse transform it.
In my audio file, I am doing some extra noise with a piece of paper while I speak. My goal is to remove the noise.

But from what I get as plots it seems like something is wrong. 
[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZ7q5.png) is what I get from the second code, while [Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8P6L.png) is from the first code. There should be the same results for the fouirer but I get two different ones. It seems like the first code is not producing anything. And even for the second I am not really convinced the inversed version is now "clean".
 Do you know what is wrong with the code?

Comment: `fft[len(data)/2 + i] = 0.0` is wrong. This does not lead to a symmetric Fourier domain. I think this needs to be `fft[-i] = 0`, if I have my Python indexing right. -- If the result of the `ifft` has a significant imaginary component (i.e. not really close to zero) then the filter is wrong.

Comment: interesting remark. The only thing that changed now is that the same variations that were shown at the beginning are not at the end as well.

Comment: As it should be, the FFT output is symmetric. In the first bit of code it only plots the first half.

Comment: thanks. I still find it confusing to be honest. How could I now "clean" the signal based on the fft?

Comment: Also, `sampling_length` is unlikely 5 seconds. You should write here the time between samples. For example, if your file is recorded at 44.1 kHz, then `Fs = 44.1e3` and `d=1/Fs` in the call to `np.fft.fftfreq`.

Comment: Regarding "cleaning" the signal, this depends on the type of distortion etc. A low-pass filter will remove some of the noise and some of the signal, usually there is more noise power than signal power at high frequencies, and so it removes more noise than signal. But I don't know what type of noise you add with your sheet of paper, it depends on its frequency content if you can remove this through a filter in the frequency domain.

Comment: Maybe record a clean signal, and a separate noise signal, and compare their frequency content. From that, find out which frequencies you want to remove to remove as much of the noise as possible, while removing as little of the signal as possible.

Comment: I thought there is a way from the results of the fourier transformation to extract the frequency where I speak and the noise from the paper. and based on that to get a clean signal.

Comment: sampling_length is not how long my audio file is!?

Comment: See [the documentation to `fftreq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftfreq.html). It says that the parameter `d` is "Sample spacing (inverse of the sampling rate)".

Comment: thank you for your comments. If you want you can summarize everything in an answer, so that I can mark it as solved

Comment: I don't think I've provided a full answer, which is why I wrote in comments rather than as an answer. I'm glad this helped you solve your problem. Maybe you can write up an answer?